# Time column average in access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have an access database one table has time column  that shows the total time from (endtime - starttime)  I need to have that column averaged (hh:mm) ss not needed.  I need to store this average into another table, and then be able to display that in a textbox. with conditional formating as far as color for certain time ranges.  I'm going to need to do this for a daily range and a monthly range, just wonder what would be the best way to accomplish this.  this monthly and daily average will need to update each time the table has records added to it.

My thoughts on this was pull the daily times into an array, then average the array, and store that average in another table.  Then use the daily average table to display in a textbox, along with the conditional formatting. and then the same thing for the monthly time average as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is by no means difficult to obtain this information from a query, time is just the decimal portion of a number.

```
 SELECT Format(Avg(CDbl([Atime2])-CDbl([ATime1])),"hh:mm:ss") AS Diff
 FROM Table;
```

Or

```
 SELECT Sum(DateDiff("n",[ATime1],[ATime2])) AS SumMins,
        Count([ATime1]) AS CountRecs, 
        Avg(DateDiff("n",[ATime1],[ATime2])) AS AvgMins
 FROM Table;
```

Furthermore, MS Access 2010 has data macros and calculated columns that are good even outside of Access.

Finally, it is not generally recommended that you store a value that becomes invalid at every edit when the value can easily be calculated.

Comment: the values in the other table are needed for historacle data, they are bound by a date field for each individual day

Comment: You can use a query similar to the above to update the table as required.